# ASP.NET MVC 2: Make culture dependent redirect before routes kick in. For example: /Home => /en/us/Home

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, redirect, localization, routes

I want to make some redirects:

```
/Home => /en/us/Home
/ => en/us/
```

Where should I put these redirects and how should I redirect to avoid getting an infinite loop?
Instead en/us I want to extract the values that the users browser is submitting.

Thank you for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things go into web.config. Look at [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/468/using-global-and-distributed-rewrite-rules/). This is for IIS7, but I think II6 supports this as well.

In your case you would add something like this into web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^en/us/?" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/en/us/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This will catch all your non /en/us URLs and redirect them to the URL that starts with /en/us/ and what ever was in the original URL.

Note that this does not have the ability to test for actual location of the user. For that you'd probably have to use some logic.